# How to create merge request and view source code Git Store in File Station Synology NAS

Tags: git, synology, nas

- Hi all. I created and set up GIT in DSM. I clone repository code and also push, pull, and switch branches normal

[image]

- I created a new branch and file in this branch, I typed some words in readme.md for testing and then I pushed it. But I can't see anything code or file in the GUI DSM, I only see my branch which is encrypted

[image]

- This DSM only has 2 items. I don't have permission to expand the role

[image]

Anyone help me: How I can see my code in DSM and create a merge request?
I appreciate your reply

Answer (score 1):

Merge requests and pull requests are not a native part of Git - and Synology's standard Git plugin is build on standard Git, so it doesn't include that functionality. (Also, the "encrypted" branch you see is just the pointer to that branch's head; you don't see your files because Synology Git wants every repo to be bare.)

It looks like the Synology can run Docker, though, so you should be able to install GitLab that way. (I'm assuming you're most familiar with GitLab because you call it a "merge request".)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Because I don't know how I can create merge request / pull request for other people to review and merge to branch master, like GitLab/GitHub I used before. This DSM only has 2 items (I updated the image above). I don't have permission to build docker GIT in DSM. It's mean I create a request branch by terminal? Please help me to clarify this. Thank you very much again